# Creating index using bulk Api java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Can I create a new index using API bulk on ES 2.4?
I start by trying the example in the official documentation that uses the method `PrepareIndex`, but it does not add a new index.
In the other way when I use Administrative API, it solves the problem, so I can create this index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
            .field("user", "kimchy")
            .field("postDate", new Date())
            .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
            .endObject();

    TransportClient client = null;

    try {
        client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Tcp non valid : machine non reconnu ");
    }
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("flux","flux1","1").setSource(builder));

    builder.flush();
    client.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elastic search instance might have a setting that prevents automatic index creation, which means that if you post a document to a non existing index it will not create it. Look for `action.auto_create_index` property in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation

Comment: Thank you Andrey ,it work for me ,by default  action.auto_create_index is "true" .when i try to add this parametre at elasticsearch.yml and i migrate between value true and false (with restarting ES) at any migration i see the diffférence . Thanks a lot :)